# Issue with using a TypeVar as an argument to a Callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I got an issue the following code, at least according to mypy:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


def do_something(a: T) -> Tuple[T, bool]:
    # Something happening here...
    return a, False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    nums = list(range(100000, 1000000))
    for r in pool.imap_unordered(do_something, nums):
        if r[1]:
            print(f"Got {r[0]}")
```

When I check it using mypy I get the following error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "imap_unordered" of "Pool" has incompatible type "Callable[[T], Tuple[T, bool]]"; expected "Callable[[int], Tuple[T, bool]]"
```

The actual type clearly should satisfy the expected type.
Did I do something wrong or is it a bug in mypy or the multiprocessing.Pool?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Does the same error occur if you remove the `print` statement at the end?

Comment: This doesn't depend on `multiprocessing`. You get the same error if you replace `pool.imap_unordered` with `map`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Yes, this error still occurs when I remove the print

Comment: Here's a minimal reproducible example of this behaviour: https://gist.github.com/gvx/1bad0371a17aaccdede0b28378be7ba2

Comment: @Jasmijn Ah, thats even more minimal, than mine, thank you. So this seems to really be a problem in mypy when using function objects with TypeVar arguments as an argument to another function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the comments by Jasmijn, here's a minimal example:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def do_something(a: T) -> T:
    return a

map(do_something, [1])
```

This fails with the same error. I think this is a limitation of `mypy`, but we can fix it by introducing an extra helper function through which we provide the type explicitly instead of `mypy` having to infer it.

```
def new_do_something(t: Type[T]) -> Callable[[T], T]:
    return do_something
```

Using the above, this no longer causes any error, while still allowing `do_something` to be generic:

```
map(new_do_something(int), [1])
```

For your original example, the modified version would look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar, Type, Callable

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


def do_something(a: T) -> Tuple[T, bool]:
    # Something happening here...
    return a, False

def new_do_something(t: Type[T]) -> Callable[[T], Tuple[T, bool]]:
    return do_something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    nums = list(range(100000, 1000000))
    for r in pool.imap_unordered(new_do_something(int), nums):
        if r[1]:
            print(f"Got {r[0]}")
```

Comment: Thank you, that really fixes the mypy error. It's not beautiful, and will need some comments to explain, but better than an ```#type: ignore```.
I really hope mypy will address this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

In mypy 1.5.1 the OP code now passes if you run the check with `--new-type-inference` flag

See:
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8275#issuecomment-1682320726

#### Original answer:

Here are a couple of alternative solutions...

1. convert `do_something` into a generic class with callable instances:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Generic, Tuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


class do_something(Generic[T]):
    def __call__(self, a: T) -> Tuple[T, bool]:
        # Something happening here...
        return a, False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    nums = list(range(100000, 1000000))
    for r in pool.imap_unordered(do_something[int](), nums):
        if r[1]:
            print(f"Got {r[0]}")
```

It doesn't look very much better but at least avoids defining an extra intermediary function.

2. since you already restricted the TypeVar to only `str` or `int` we can use specific `@overload`s instead of making it Generic:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import overload, Any


@overload
def do_something(a: int) -> tuple[int, bool]: ...
@overload
def do_something(a: str) -> tuple[str, bool]: ...

def do_something(a: Any) -> tuple[Any, bool]:
    # Something happening here...
    return a, False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    nums = list(range(100000, 1000000))
    for r in pool.imap_unordered(do_something, nums):
        if r[1]:
            print(f"Got {r[0]}")
```